# QDSL Calling .eq() on entities vs IDs

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, querydsl

In QueryDSL, is there any difference between calling

```
where(entity.id.eq(entity2.id))
```

and

```
where(entity.eq(entity2))
```

(`entity, entity2` are different `QClass` instances)?

And what is preferred?

The first version is used regularly, and I can see at least one usage of the 2nd in the official docs:

```
.leftJoin(company).on(customer.company.eq(company))
```

([qdsl-4.4.0-joins](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.4.0/reference/html_single/#d0e1205))

In my concrete example, when I let the logger show the final SQL, both compare on IDs. But in the 2nd version, the id column is right on the "parent table":

```
BCcgTeacherEOMetadata teacher = new BCcgTeacherEOMetadata("teacher2");
    HibernateQuery<Object> uselessQuery = getQueryDslTemplate().createQueryFrom(courseStudent)
            .join(courseStudent.course.teacher, teacher)
            .where(courseStudent.course.teacher.eq(teacher));
    System.out.println(uselessQuery.fetchFirst());
```

yields `... where bcccoursee1_.TEACHER_ID=bccteacher2_.TEACHER_ID ...`
whereas comparing on ids yields `... where bccteacher2_.TEACHER_ID=bccteacher2_.TEACHER_ID ...`
(`*Metadata` is basically a `QClass`)

Comment: The performance aspect of this question depends on how the associtions are mapped and if inheritance strategies to applied to any of the entities. However, in general, Hibernate will generate the exact same SQL for both cases. Its perfectly able to rewrite either statement.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you specifiy what you compare on.

where(entity.id.eq(entity2.id))

In the second case, it is comparing on equality of the two objects.

According to eq in the official documentation:

```
eq

public BooleanExpression eq(T constant)

Description copied from interface: ExtendedSubQuery
Create a this == right expression

Specified by:
    eq in interface ExtendedSubQuery<T>
Parameters:
    constant - rhs of the comparison
Returns:
    this == right
```

where(entity.eq(entity2))
.leftJoin(company).on(customer.company.eq(company))

If you want an exact comparison, on a field you really want to compare on explicitly, use the first case.

Comment: But how's the 1st more exact? I get that it's more verbose and telling... But if it compares two objects instead of the id fields and since the ids serve as unique identifiers.. should be the same precision, no? (Perhaps it'd be less efficient then? But I can't see what's being done under the hood.)